# ui-sref-active="active" not working in my navbar menu

Tags: css, angularjs, controller, css-selectors

I have side nav menu that when you hover over a image link changes from example (`imgOn` to `imgOff`). The images link to a page. The issue is when I click outside the nav menu the image does not stay active.

CSS:

```
#icon-performance{content: url(../app/images/performance-white.png);}
#icon-performance:hover,
#icon-performance.focus{content: url(../app/images/performance-blue.png);}

#icon-overview{content: url(../app/images/overview-white.png);
#icon-overview:hover,
#icon-overview.focus{content: url(../app/images/overview-blue.png);}

#icon-audience{content: url(../app/images/audience-white.png);}
#icon-audience:hover,
#icon-audience.focus{content: url(../app/images/audience-blue.png);}

#icon-socialmedia{content: url(../app/images/socialmedia-white.png);}
#icon-socialmedia:hover,
#icon-socialmedia.focus{content: url(../app/images/socialmedia-blue.png);}

#icon-email{content: url(../app/images/email-white.png);}
#icon-email:hover,
#icon-email.focus{content: url(../app/images/email-blue.png);}'
```

using :focus does not do the trick.

index page:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" >
                 <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="performance"><i id="icon-performance"></i><br>PERFORMANCE SNAPSHOT</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="overview"><i id="icon-overview"></i><br>OVERVIEW</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="audience"><i id="icon-audience"></i><br>AUDIENCE</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="socialMedia"><i id="icon-socialmedia"></i><br>SOCIAL MEDIA</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="emailCampaign"><i id="icon-email"></i><br>EMAIL CAMPAIGN</a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
</nav>`

controller:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/overview")

$stateProvider
    .state("overview", {
        url: "/overview",
        templateUrl: "partials/partialOverview.html"
    })
    .state('audience',{
        url: "/audience",
        templateUrl: "partials/partialAudience.html"
    })
    .state('socialmedia',{
        url: "/socialmedia",
        templateUrl: "partials/partialSocialMedia.html"
    })
    .state('emailcampaign',{
        url: "/EmailCampaign",
        templateUrl: "partials/partialEmailCampaign.html"
    })
    .state("performance", {
        url: "/Performance",
        templateUrl: "partials/partialPerformance.html"
    })
});})();
```

Comment: Why is `angularjs` tagged then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640553/how-to-add-a-hover-background-image-style-on-a-div-the-angularjs-way

Comment: because this is used with the angularjs mvc framework

Comment: How do you "select" an image?

Comment: I use a controller, see my additions above, i'm new to angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

HTML:

```
<li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="performance"><i id="icon-performance"></i><br>PERFORMANCE SNAPSHOT</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.nav > li > .active #icon-performance{content: url(../app/images/performance-blue.png);}
```

applied this to all the nav images.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using `:focus`. The CSS focus selector only works on form inputs and hyperlinks. You need to do this with JavaScript.

Angular example where the focus class toggles when clicked:

```
<img ng-class="{focus: hasFocus}" ng-click="hasFocus = !hasFocus">
```

CSS:

```
#icon-performance{
    content: url(../app/images/performance-white.png);
}

#icon-performance:hover,
#icon-performance.focus{
    content: url(../app/images/performance-blue.png);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source or example with javascript or jquery?